# Not able to complete the Retrofit request?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have to send the `JSON` as a `Post` request through `Retrofit`. To this I have created a Json Object :

```
 private JSONObject yourJSON(){

    JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray  jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
    try{
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject2);
        jsonObject2.put("duration", "12");
        jsonObject1.put("region", "NYC");
        jsonObject1.put("or", jsonArray);
        jsonRoot.put("q", jsonObject1);
        jsonRoot.put("sort", "recent");
    }catch (JSONException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonRoot;
}
```

Then I am using this `JSON` to send the data by following code

```
 RestApiAdapter restAdapter = new RestApiAdapter();
 RoomListingAPI apiservice = restAdapter.providesRestAdapter().create(RoomListingAPI.class);
 JSONObject response = apiservice.getRoomListing("qwerty","application/json", yourJSON());
```

## API method

```
public interface RoomListingAPI {
@POST("/api/listings/search")
JSONObject getRoomListing(@Header("x-parse-session-token") String token, @Header("Content-Type") String type, @Body JSONObject json);
}
```

My goal is to send the JSON and received the JSON but it's not working. What I am doing wrong here. I am also sending the correct `JSON`. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: i don't understand what issue you are facing.

Comment: It's not working. I cannot see any response from Retrofit

Comment: `it's not working` does not mean much. `I cannot see` can range from your screen being off to the internet permission missing. what have you done in terms of debugging the problem?

Comment: @njzk2 Sorry. My bad! just pasted the stacktrace. BTW is this the right way to pass JSON ?

Comment: next step: take the error, google it, find a bazillion answers

Comment: I tried but didn't get any idea about it

Comment: I found this problem `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` but after adding permission I am getting Bad request

Comment: solve your problems one at a time, and if needed, ask a different question for each different problem that you face.

Comment: 1. Please post your `RestApiAdapter`

2. Make sure you set log level to full.
 
`setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setLog(new AndroidLog("Retrofit"))`

3. Re-copy the stacktrace

Comment: @Fadils After making these changes and async instead of sync I am getting `edit-2` stacktrace

Comment: @all Is this the right way to send `JSON` and recieve `JSON` ? Because when I am using `pojo` in other API method Everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call your network operation on a background task instead. Otherwise, `NetworkOnMainThreadException` will be thrown.

Now retrofit has two modes. Synchronous or Asynchronous.

You're using a synchronous mode, presumably called in your main thread.

What you can do now is to change to asynchronous mode (using retrofit callback).

That is, change from:

```
public interface RoomListingAPI {
    @POST("/api/listings/search")
    JSONObject getRoomListing(@Header("x-parse-session-token") String token, @Header("Content-Type") String type, @Body JSONObject json);
}
```

To:

```
public interface RoomListingAPI {
    @POST("/api/listings/search")
    void getRoomListing(@Header("x-parse-session-token") String token, @Header("Content-Type") String type, @Body JSONObject json,  Callback<JsonObject> responseCallback);
}
```

To get the JsonObject return response:

```
apiservice.getRoomListing("qwerty","application/json", yourJSON(),
     new Callback<JsonObject>() {
         @Override
         public void success(JsonObject jsonObject, Response response) {
              // jsonObject is what you're looking for
         }

         @Override
         public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
              // do something with the error 
         }
});
```

Also, it's better to use gson library. Thus use JsonObject instead of JSONObject. Different letter-case, different library, better performance.

Comment: I have already changed to `AsyncCall` but still getting an error. Check out the Edit-3 section. Is it relate to `JSON` ?

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions about that case. Basically, are you sure you are returning JsonObject instead of string?

Comment: Actually Yes, This is one instance of Json what I am getting in response : http://pastebin.com/39bN1x23

Comment: Yep, once everything is correct, then everything should be OK. Btw, can you please mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: I am doing but still I am having same problem

Comment: basically, you're asking two different questions. First is, the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, which already solved. Second, is you're having a problem parsing the return result, which is a different problem. IMHO, you should create a new thread for that so that the community can benefit from clear question and answer instead of having everything mixed in one thread.